# How do I give the legend a background color in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

The colors from the legend are blending in with the colors on my stackplot. Seemingly, this appears to be by default (as I have not touched any color settings). How would I fix this? Is there a way to give my legend a background color? I have already tried using the `facecolor` argument.

Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

# hours worked each day on the project 
dev1 = [8, 6, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0]
dev2 = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4]
dev3 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]



plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

labels = ['Developer 1', 'Developer 2', 'Developer 3']


plt.stackplot(days, dev1, dev2, dev3, labels=labels)

plt.legend(loc=(0.05, 0.07))
# plt.legend(loc=(0.05, 0.07), facecolor='white')    I have tried this as well
plt.title('My Awesome Stack Plot')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Weird. I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xTXm.png).

Comment: Could it have do do with the version? I have breifly used matplotlib in the past, and that is the way I remember it (by default). I should also mention, I've tried this in jupyter notebooks and jupyter lab

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue. The `frameon=True` argument did the trick.

```
plt.legend(loc=(0.05, 0.07),frameon=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add :

```
plt.legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('Color or Color_code')
```

You can find it in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

Comment: Like this `plt.legend(loc=(0.05, 0.07)).get_frame().set_facecolor('white')`? That did not work